# Errors when trying to use custom route in Umbraco 7 to generate sitemap.xml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

I building an Umbraco 7 site and have created a Sitemap document type which renders an XML sitemap in its Razor view.

This works fine and runs from the URL /sitemap/.

I am now trying to use custom routing to make this sitemap available at /sitemap.xml. Following various online advice I've created an implementation of `IApplicationEventHandler` with the following method:

```
public void OnApplicationInitialized(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
{
    //custom route
    RouteTable.Routes.MapUmbracoRoute(
    "sitemap",
    "sitemap.xml",
    new
    {
        controller = "XMLSitemap"
    },
    new XmlSitemapRouteHandler());
}
```

The `XmlSitemapRouteHandler` implements `UmbracoVirtualNodeRouteHandler` and overrides the following method:

```
protected override IPublishedContent FindContent(RequestContext requestContext, UmbracoContext umbracoContext)
{
    var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(umbracoContext);

    return umbracoHelper.TypedContent(_sitemapNodeId);
}
```

For now I have a very simple controller associated:

```
public class XMLSitemapController : RenderMvcController
{
    public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
    {
        return this.CurrentTemplate(model);
    }
}
```

When I load /sitemap.xml in the browser I get the following exception:

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: umbracoContext

This at the line `var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(umbracoContext);`. I get the same when I use `UmbracoContext.Current` in place of `umbracoContext`.

It seems the UmbracoContext is not being created. My application uses dependency injection (StructureMap) and does specify a binding for UmbracoContext:

```
For<Umbraco.Web.UmbracoContext>().Use(() => Umbraco.Web.UmbracoContext.Current);
```

I wondered if this was related to the .xml extension so I tried changing the custom route URL to "sitemapxml". Now when I load this URL I get the following exception:

> The RouteData must contain an item named 'action' with a non-empty string value.

I did find some advice [here](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-5445) which suggests it's possible to use `UmbracoContext.EnsureContext` in such cases, so I've tried updating the route handler method to the following:

```
protected override IPublishedContent FindContent(RequestContext requestContext, UmbracoContext umbracoContext)
{
    var httpBase = new System.Web.HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
    UmbracoContext.EnsureContext(
        httpBase,
        Umbraco.Core.ApplicationContext.Current,
        new Umbraco.Web.Security.WebSecurity(httpBase, Umbraco.Core.ApplicationContext.Current),
        true); 

    var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);

    return umbracoHelper.TypedContent(1090);
}
```

Although the code is reporting that this EnsureContext method is obsolete I do at least now see that UmbracoContext.Current is a valid reference. However, I still get an exception, this time:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is thrown from an Umbraco assembly at `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoVirtualNodeRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)`.

So I'm stuck. I had thought it would be relatively easy to provide a custom route like this. Perhaps I'm taking the wrong approach entirely. Advice much appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `http://www.yoursite.be/?alttemplate=XMLSitemap`? it renders directly your sitemap xml without doing code.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful to know, but I'm afraid it doesn't get me closer to answering my question about making Umbraco-rendered XML available from a .xml extension.

Answer (score 5):

had the same problem and looked into this a bit further. Problem appears in `UmbracoVirtualNodeRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)` because `UmbracoContext.Current` is null but is needed to create the `PublishedContentRequest`. I don't think you can solve this by inherit `UmbracoVirtualNodeRouteHandler`.

My solution is to implement IRouteHandler instead and take some code from Umbraco.Web:

```
public class XmlSitemapRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
       UmbracoContext current = UmbracoContext.Current;

        if (current == null)
        {
            var httpBase = new System.Web.HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
            current = UmbracoContext.EnsureContext(
            httpBase,
            ApplicationContext.Current,
            new WebSecurity(httpBase, ApplicationContext.Current),
            UmbracoConfig.For.UmbracoSettings(),
            UrlProviderResolver.Current.Providers,
            false);
        }

        IPublishedContent publishedContent = this.FindContent(requestContext, current);
        if (publishedContent == null)
        {
            return new NotFoundHandler();
        }


        Uri originalRequestUrl = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;

        Uri cleanedUmbracoUrl = UriUtility.UriToUmbraco(originalRequestUrl);
        current.PublishedContentRequest = new PublishedContentRequest(cleanedUmbracoUrl, current.RoutingContext, UmbracoConfig.For.UmbracoSettings().WebRouting, (string s) => Roles.Provider.GetRolesForUser(s))
        {
            PublishedContent = publishedContent
        };
        this.PreparePublishedContentRequest(current.PublishedContentRequest);
        RenderModel value = new RenderModel(current.PublishedContentRequest.PublishedContent, current.PublishedContentRequest.Culture);
        requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens.Add("umbraco", value);
        requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens.Add("umbraco-doc-request", current.PublishedContentRequest);
        requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens.Add("umbraco-context", current);
        requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens.Add("umbraco-custom-route", true);

        return new MvcHandler(requestContext);
    }

    protected IPublishedContent FindContent(RequestContext requestContext, UmbracoContext umbracoContext)
    {
        var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(umbracoContext);
        return umbracoHelper.TypedContent(_sitemapNodeId);
    }
    protected virtual void PreparePublishedContentRequest(PublishedContentRequest publishedContentRequest)
    {
        publishedContentRequest.Prepare();
    }

}
```

You will also need a custom Route-extension:

```
    public static Route MapXmlSitemapRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults, XmlSitemapRouteHandler virtualNodeHandler, object constraints = null, string[] namespaces = null)
    {
        Route route = routes.MapRoute(name, url, defaults, constraints, namespaces);
        route.RouteHandler = virtualNodeHandler;
        return route;
    }
```

You can now create your route like this in your implementation of `IApplicationEventHandler`:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapXmlSitemapRoute(
            "sitemap",
            "sitemap.xml",
            new
            {
                controller = "XMLSitemap",
                action = "index"
            },
            new XmlSitemapRouteHandler());
```

Comment: This IRouteHandler implementation is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

My suggestion would be to take a step back and just try to get a basic custom route to work. Then you can work your way from there.
I just wrote a blogpost about custom routes in Umbraco, it might help you.
You can find it here: https://blog.sandervanlooveren.be/posts/custom-routes-in-umbraco-for-better-seo/

Comment: this is not an answer